# Stretch SVG background image?

Tags: css, svg, background-image

It's easy to stretch a png background image:

```
.stretched-logo-bg {
    background: url("../img/curve.png") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

this won't work with an SVG background though

```
.stretched-logo-bg {
    background: url("../img/curve.svg") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

it won't get stretched, it will maintain its aspect ratio and just center.

At least in Chrome 52

Comment: you can do that Robert?? where is that referenced in specs? would love to read details

Comment: @MichaelMullany my answer contains a link to the spec section

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to override the preserveAspectRatio of the SVG you are displaying you can use an [SVG fragment identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers) to do that e.g.

```
.stretched-logo-bg {
    background: url("../img/curve.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: worked nicely in Chrome on MacOS, but for some reason it did not work on Windows (SVG did not show up at all)

Comment: I have to correct myself - it does work fine in Chrome on Windows also, I had messed up something else unrelated...

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe that you can make a SVG to distort like you can with PNGs.

However, if you are mostly supporting modern browsers, you can add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` attribute to the SVG tag.

For example:

```
<svg version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none" .. etc`
```